# Django: existing database foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am wondering about how to work with Django when it comes to an existing database

For instance, let say we have the following tables

```
Table Student
ID  primary key
First_Name Text
Last_Name Text

Table Classes
CID primary key
SKF  ForeignKey  
Class Text
```

Ok, this database is already created and has data inside and the foreign and primary keys are already set up. Now, when creating our model, how do we tell Django the foreignkey is the SKF field? If you need any more information please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built-in function ([`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models)) for auto-generating models from an existing database.

Of course it also takes care of generating the corresponding ForeignKeys.

Comment: What will the foreignkey look like. When I use inspectdb, I see the field(code) that is suppose to be the foreignkey but it does not state if it is the foreignkey and I can not get data that is related. I can access the parent table and the child table separately but I am not able to get related data between the two tables.

Comment: What does the field look like and how are you trying to get the related data?

Comment: My primary
sid = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)

My foreignkey look like this

   sfk = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', blank=False, null=False)

q = Student.objects.get(sid=1)

Now how would get to the related data?

Comment: It's strange that sfk isn't a ForeignKey. But you could modify it yourself to get it working.

Comment: How would I go about that? the sfk is what Django generated when I used inspectdb

Comment: Modify the model's attribute to this: `sfk = models.ForeignKey('Student', ...)` and then you can do queries like this: `student = class.skf`, `classes = student.skf_set` etc.

Comment: Can't get it to work. You know of any good books or tutorials that relates to using existing databases?

Comment: The official Django documentation has a [HowTo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/) for using legacy databases.